# ¿No puedo consumir la sesión creada en express-session?

Tags: express, fetch, get, express-session

Mi código busca crear una sesión y poder consultar dicha sesión. El problema una vez que se ya se creo la sesión al consultarla por medio de una petición GET me regresa Undefine tengo el siguiente código.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="Post">Iniciar sesión (POST)</button>
    <button id="Get">Obtener sesión (GET)</button>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Java Script:

```
document.getElementById("Post").addEventListener("click", POST);
document.getElementById("Get").addEventListener("click", GET);

const url = "http://localhost:4000/session";

function GET() {
  fetch(url, {withCredentials:true})
  .then(res => res.text())
  .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
  .then(response => console.log('Success:', response));
}

function POST () {
  fetch(url, { method: 'POST' })
  .then(res => res.text())
  .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
  .then(response => console.log('Success:', response));
}
```

Express.js:

```
const express = require ('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const cors = require ('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'Secret-Key',
    saveUninitialized: true
  }));

  app.post('/session', (req, res) => {
    req.session.username = 'User-1';
    res.send( `Sesión iniciada como ${req.session.username}`);
});

  app.get('/session', async (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.username) {
      res.send(req.session.username);
    } else {
      res.send("sesión no iniciada");
    }
  });

app.listen(4000, ()=>{
    console.log('server runing in port 4000')
});
```

Como pueden ver en el código al hacer clic en el botón Iniciar sesión envía una petición Get que crea la sesión con el nombre de usuario "Usuario-1" y envía el mensaje "Sesión iniciada como Usuario-1" pero al dar clic en el boton Obtener Sesión debería enviarme como respuesta "Usuario-1" y si hago la petición en Postam esto se ejecuta de manera correcta pero si hago la peticion por medio del HTML dando clic al boton Obtener Sesión me responde "sesion no iniciada" lo que quiere decir que la sesión es undefine apesara de que ya inicie la sesión dando clic al botón Iniciar sesión.

La pregunta es ¿porque no me regresa el username ya creada en la sesión al hacer la petición Get pero al hacer la petición Get en Postman si me regresa el username creado previamente con la petición Post?